# fix an issue in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

First excuse my english;
i'm a newbie in maven 
 i have a problem with a pom.xml file, and exacly with the maven-copy-plugin that i don't khow how to fixe it.. so anyone can help me to write right my pom ? thank you,

this is the exception that i have :

```
<code>[INFO`enter code here`] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:jar:0.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:0.2.3: Plugin com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:0.2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:jar:0.2.3
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spring-security Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:jar:0.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:0.2.3: Plugin com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:0.2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:jar:0.2.3
[WARNING] The POM for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:jar:0.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available</code>
```

the pom.xml that i have is the following :

```
<code>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.krams</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-tutorial</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-security Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <pluginRepositories>

    <!-- Repo for maven-copy-plugin -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>evgeny-goldin.org</id>
        <name>Evgeny Goldin Repository</name>
        <url>http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </pluginRepository> 

  </pluginRepositories>
   <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <spring.core.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
    <spring.security.core.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.core.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.1.0.M1</spring.data.jpa.version>

    <cglib.version>2.2</cglib.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.10</aspectj.version>

    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.16</mysql.connector.version>
    <hibernate.entitymanager.version>3.6.3.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version>
    <hibernate.jpa-api.version>2.0-cr-1</hibernate.jpa-api.version>
    <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>

    <querydsl.version>2.2.5</querydsl.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>

    <javax.servlet-api.version>2.5</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <javax.jstl-taglibs.version>1.1.2</javax.jstl-taglibs.version>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <mockito.version>1.8.5</mockito.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <maven.copy.plugin.version>0.2.3</maven.copy.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.apt.plugin.version>1.0</maven.apt.plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- A seamless aspect-oriented extension to the Java programming language -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cglib is a powerful, high performance and quality Code Generation Library, 
    It is used to extend JAVA classes and implements interfaces at runtime.  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) encapsulates, as simple tags, core 
    functionality common to many JSP applications. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction 
    for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end 
    user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  MySQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate and JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.jpa-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- QueryDSL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax Servlet. This needs to be included for runtime only! -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-security-tutorial</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.apt.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.goldin.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-copy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.copy.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <!-- Select compile phase so that resources are copied first before being packaged! -->
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</targetPath>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/META-INF</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <repositories>

    <!-- For main Spring releases -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <name>JBoss repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>

  </repositories>


</project>

</code>
```

thank you a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion i can make is to put the contents you have in src/main/META-INFO into src/main/resources/META-INF which will result in automatically being copied into the target/classes folder which make the copy plugin superfluous.
An an other recommendation is to use a repository manager [instead putting the repositories into the pom](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/).

Comment: thanks Mr. khmarbaise, but any of these suggestions worked, if somewone chould help me fixe dependency problems in my pom.xml;
in fact, the exception is
Plugin com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:0.2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:jar:0.2.3: Failure to find com.goldin.plugins:maven-copy-plugin:pom:0.2.3 in http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of evgeny-goldin.org has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: In that case remove the folder inside .m2/repository/..evgeny-goldin.org/...manuall and just retry it.